# CakePHP, Setting a complex/multiple find condition for a multi select box

Tags: php, cakephp, multi-select, cakephp-model

I have a multi-select box named Manufacturer Name that is displaying correctly, even clickable for multi search.  When I run the search I am not getting any results from my database using the complex find conditions I set.  I've tried to use Complex-Find-Conditions from the bakery, and other various websites but no avail.

```
//This my index.ctp
<?=$form->create('ManufacturersProductsLine', array('action'=>'index'));?>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?=$f->label('ManufacturersProductsLine.manufacturer_id', 'Manufacturer Name:'); ?>
                <?=$f->select('ManufacturersProductsLine.manufacturer_id', $manufacturers, null, array('multiple'=>'multiple', 'style'=>'height:100px;'))?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?=$f->label('ManufacturersProductsLine.name', 'Product Name:'); ?>
                <?=$f->text('ManufacturersProductsLine.name', array('style'=>'width:140px;'));?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label></label>
                <input name="Search" class="blue" type="submit" value="Search Product Lines" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Commented out is things I have tried in my controller for setting the multiple find conditions.

```
//This is my manufacturers_products_lines_controller.php
function index() {
    $conditions = array();
    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        $data = $this->data;

        $conditions[] = "(LOWER(ManufacturersProductsLine.manufacturer_id) LIKE '%{$data['ManufacturersProductsLine']['manufacturer_id']}%')";
        //$conditions = array("ManufacturersProductsLine.name" => array("Akuret", "Bridgestone", "American Radials") );

        debug($this->data);
    }
    $this->Manufacturer->recursive = 1;
    $this->set('manufacturersproductslines', $manufacturersproductslines = $this->paginate('ManufacturersProductsLine', $conditions));
    $Manufacturer = getModel('Manufacturer');
    $this->set('manufacturers', $Manufacturer->find('list'));
    //$this->ManufacturersProductsLine->recursive = 0;
    //$this->Post->find('all', array('conditions' => array('ManufacturersProductsLine.manufacturer_id' =>array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13))));

}
```

When I debug and search I am getting the following.

```
Array
(
[ManufacturersProductsLine] => Array
    (
        [manufacturer_id] => Array
            (
                [0] => 1
                [1] => 2
            )

        [name] => 
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the query condition to this

```
$conditions[] = "ManufacturersProductsLine.manufacturer_id IN (" . implode( ',', $data['ManufacturersProductsLine']['manufacturer_id'] . ")";
```

Comment: Let Cake handle the SQL generation: `$conditions["ManufacturersProductsLine.manufacturer_id"] = $data['ManufacturersProductsLine']['manufacturer_id'];` If a condition is an array, it is automatically converted to "x IN (y)"

Comment: Thank you Nickf!  I didn't know you could automatically create the IN SQL statement.  I had actually solved my own issue like this (see below), but your way is much cleaner.  
foreach ($this->data['ManufacturersProductsLine']['manufacturer_id'] AS $key => $value) {
$conditions['or'][] = 'ManufacturersProductsLine.manufacturer_id ='.$value;}